# Recursive function producing a sequence of disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

> $f : X \to X$ is an injective function.
>
>  The recursive sequence of sets $Z_0, Z_1, Z_2,\dots$ is defined by the following rules:
>
>  1) $Z_0 = X \setminus f(X)$
>
>  2) $Z_{n+1} = f(Z_n)$ for any $n \geq 0.$
>
>  Prove by induction on $n$ that for any $k \geq n + 1$ the sets $Z_n$ and $Z_k$ are disjoint.

I am familiar with the principles behind the proof by induction and I still cannot prove even the base case (k=0). I am unsure how are we certain that the function of the previous set is surely producing a new set without any common entries ($f(Z_m)  ∩ f(Z_{m+1}) = \emptyset$).

Comment: You’ve written $\cup$ on the last line when I think you mean $\cap.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Z_n=f^n(Z_0)$ hence $Z_0 =X\setminus f(X)$ is clearly disjoint from $Z_n$ for all $n$. That gives you the base case for the induction.

Assume that $Z_n$ is disjoint from all $Z_{n+k}$ for $k>0$.  For contradiction assume that $Z_{n+1} $ and $Z_{n+l}$ share the point $z$ for $l>1$. But since $f$ is injective it will have an inverse on its image, hence $f^{-1}(z)$ will be in both $Z_n$ and $Z_{n+l-1}$ which contradicts the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @Thomas ‘It will have an inverse on its image’. Is certainly correct.